# Android - MultipartEntity and dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, androidhttpclient

I recently migrate my project from Eclipse to Android Studio (I do not fully control this IDE yet). In this project, I have a file uploader AsyncTask which send multipart over http. To do this, I use org.apache.httpcomponents. I created following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4'
    ...
}
```

---

In my java AsyncTask code:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addBinaryBody(...);
builder.addBinaryBody(...);
builder.addBinaryBody(...);
HttpEntity entity = builder.build(); // < throw exception
```

---

The exception I obtain at startup upload:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.toString(ContentType.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.<init>(MultipartFormEntity.java:52)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.buildEntity(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:226)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder.build(MultipartEntityBuilder.java:230)
```

---

I think there is a conflict between `android.jar > httpcomponents` and the `org.apache.httpcomponents` dependency but I don't find a solution to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I had the same issue - try to use the http-android-client (this also relies on the `httmime` but requires 4.3). This worked for me:

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
  compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
      exclude module: "httpclient"
  }
}
```

Comment: @soey Thanks for the answer it saved me.Working totally fine.

Answer (score 11):

**Solution for Android Studio**

Right click on app foleder in left- >Open Module Settings -> Dependencies-> click '+' -> 1. library  Dependencie

now "choose file Dependencies" box will come - provide input 'httpmime:4.4' and click search button.

it will show the dependencie file. Select that file and click ok.

wait ... it will add the jar and Gradle script will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies {
 compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    // httpmime:4.2.1'  also worked 
    exclude module: "httpclient"
}
```