# unable to import files import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode; import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;

Tags: android, android-support-library

hello i was trying to use MultipartEntity but i was unable to use them can u solve this how to make them import in my project.
[image]

it shows an error message that

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470486/android-multipartentity-and-dependencies

Comment: http://tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/

Comment: change your compileSdkVersion to 22 and make changes in dependencies as: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1' in your app gradle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the legacy http library in `build.gradle` if you are using Android Studio

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just Use this in your build.gradle

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

or You can Use this librery **Okhttp** 
Here You Can read

http://square.github.io/okhttp/

its So simple for call Webservices and Upload Image As well as

Comment: It worked for me tq nw im trying to use Okhttp

Answer (score -1):

change your compileSdkVersion to 22 and make changes in dependencies as: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1' in your app gradle